# Mongoose callback returns empty on production environment but non-empty local

Tags: angularjs, node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

I have a `nodejs` application using `express` and `mongoose`. The frontend is an `AngularJS` app.
When running on my local machine the `express` route gives the correct result from `MongoDB` but on the production environment I get an empty result (`[]`).

The `User` schema is defined as follows:

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');

module.exports = mongoose.model('Users', {
    Username : String,
    Password : String,
    UniqueID : String,
    Coordinates : Array
}, 'Users');
```

The `express` route which gets these results is:

```
app.get('/coordinates/:userId', function (req, res) {
    User.findOne({UniqueID: req.params.userId}, function (err, user) {
        if (err) res.send(err);
        else {
            res.send(user.Coordinates);
        }
    });
});
```

On my local machine I get a response: `[{x: 0, y: 0}, {x: 25, y: 25}]`, but on the server I get `[]`.

The route is called with the following `AngularJS` snippet:

```
$http.get('/coordinates/<userId>').then(function (response) {
        $scope.coordinates = !_.isEmpty(response.data) ? response.data : [];            
    }, function (response) {
    });
```

I have no clue what the issue could be.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue and this is what I did to solve it

- Verify your mongoose version and the dev mongo version
- Verify that your mongoose and prod mongo version are compatible (I had an incompatible version, and fixing it worked)
- Very basic, I am sure you would have checked that , but verify that the table has data!

Comment: The server was using an older mongodb than my local env so I changed that and now I am getting an empty response local as well... It seems as the arrays aren't fetched

Comment: Which mongo did you update? Did you downgrade local mongo or upgrade the prod mongo?

Comment: downgrade local. It seems as if the Array types are not fetched at all.

Comment: okay... So instead of downgrading local, put it back again. And verify that its working. Then upgrade the production to use the same mongo version

Answer (score 0):

Stupid me, it turns out it was a PEBCAK. Somehow the production database contained 2 users with the same UniqueID (not very unique, I know) and the findOne returned just the one I wasn't expecting...